# Can I build boost for mingw and windows from same folder?

Tags: c++, boost

So I have a folder with boost 1.44.0 and I need both msvc and MinGW binary libraries. I have already done the msvc build and need to do the MinGW gcc build next. Can I build from the same folder? My reasoning is this should not create a problem as the *.a/*.so libraries are just placed in the same lib folder but the headers/sources and not modified. Is this correct understanding? My goal is to have the same build tree and the libraries in the same folder.

The two builds are not done concurrently of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fine. Libraries are just files on the harddisk so they can easily coexist in the same folder, as long as they have different names.

In summary: yes your assumptions are correct.

Comment: To expand on that.. The Boost Build system is designed so you can exactly that. The libraries are built with different names to cover many of the different variations that people usually want, the big one being the different compilers. And to correct one aspect: You can do more than one compiler build at the same time. That is you can build mingw and msvc at the same time.